# Atom: how to diff two files using split-diff

Tags: atom-editor

It compares my file to the latest version checked into git. How do I compare two files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use a package. I use [split-diff](https://atom.io/packages/split-diff) which compares files in tow panes side by side. You need to open each file in a custom pane and then invoke command split-diff:toggle. See package documentation for more info.

Or you may use [compare-files](https://atom.io/packages/compare-files) package showing a diff of two files

Comment: `compare-files` stopped working, `split-diff` is the way to go!